# How to decide the proper layout of django models?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Yes, so I had been working on a django project, where I can extend a model class or use the same model putting the unused fields null. I am  not sure which approach is better? I am using Postgres as my db.

So, there are two cases:

Case1:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
    field7 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field8 = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    field9 = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    field10 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, default=0)
```

The thing is I have to store data in two forms. For one case, field 1, field8, field9 will always remain null and field10 will always remain 0.
In case 2, I can split this models in two ways, as shown below:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
    field7 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Model2(Model1):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field8 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field9 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field10 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
```

I was curious about how much memory will we be able to save on using the second case of model creation. Or how advantageous is it to use the second method than the first method?
As much as I have studied, postgres saves the null cases with null bitmaps, which take 1 byte for upto 8 fields and 2 bytes for 9-16 fields. So, theoritically, having null field in the CharField case, should add 1 bit each.
On the other hand having a default value for decimal field that is 0, might take more space.
Great, if someone could provide more info regarding this both in terms of storage and querying.

Comment: Don't worry about the disk space differences between the two options. Think about  which solution is best in terms of bussines rules and models.

Comment: Like @grouchoboy mentions, focus more on how you query the data, how you will join it etc.